# Contar registros insertados de csv con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Antes de explicar mi problema quiero recalcar que ya mire las posibles respuestas a mi pregunta, y todas tratan con algo diferente. Lo que quiero hacer es que al importar un archivo CSV a una tabla me muestre el numero de filas que he insertado o que tiene el archivo, o si no se ha seleccionado un archivo que muestre un mensaje de que tengo seleccionar uno, el archivo me sube bien, pero el problema es que no me muestra el conteo de las filas, hasta ahora tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php        
if(isset($_POST['importar'])){        
echo "<center>";
echo "<img src='../IMAGENES/candado.png'>";     
echo "</center>";
}
?>
<?php
extract($_POST);
if($action == "upload"){
$archivo = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$row = 1; 
$fp = fopen ($archivo,"r"); 
while ($data = fgetcsv ($fp, 1000, ";")){ 
  $num = count ($data); 
  print " <br>"; 
  $row++; 
  $insertar="INSERT INTO acta_entrega_huawei (NUMERO, PLANILLA, N_PEDIDO, 
  PROCESO, FECHA_E_FAC, FECHA_E_CON, FECHA_OPE, OBSERVACIONES) VALUES 
  ('$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]', '$data[4]', '$data[5]', 
  '$data[6]', '$data[7]');

mysql_query($insertar);
} 
fclose ($fp); 

echo "<td><center><font face=\"arial\" color=\"green\"><b>Registros 
insertados ".$row."</b></font></center></td>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Revisando tu perfil podemos ver que hay muchas preguntas que nuestros usuario han respondido y no has calificado, recuerda que Stack Overflow **no es un foro**, puedes contribuir al crecimiento del sitio, haciendo **click** en la paloma de color verde que se encuentra al lado de las respuestas a tus preguntas.

Comment: Asi permitiras que futuros usuarios con tu mismo problemas obtengan una respuesta mas fiable a sus inconvenientes.

Comment: Ya he dicho por enecima vez que el puntaje de mi reputacion no me permite que se vea mi votacion o calificacion, me aparece: "¡Gracias por tu comentario! Los votos emitidos por usuarios que tengan menos de 15 puntos de reputacion no..."

Comment: No es necesario dar una calificacion, pero con el solo hecho de **aceptar** la respuesta como la mejor, ganas 2 puntos de reputacion, no importa la resputacion que tengas, siempre podras aceptarla

Comment: Disculpas a todos ya he aceptado todas las respuestas que me han ayudado, Gracias Ivan.

Comment: No hay de que, recuerda que esta comunidad esta para servirte, y la mejor manera de agradecer a quien te ayuda es aceptando su respuesta, asi quien la busque en un futuro encontrara una respuesta acertada